# Docker daemon fails to start: inotify_add_watch: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, inotify

I've installed lxc-docker-1.5.0 under minimal Debian Wheezy. I've also installed apparmor and had it enabled using parameters "apparmor=1 security=apparmor" in grub's linux default command line variable.

That's all configuration I've done so far. Since I don't have Internet access on this machine, I couldn't execute the get.docker.com script. Module aufs seems available.

When trying to use docker, I get:

```
# docker version
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

There is no process "docker -d" running, and when trying to launch it:

```
# docker -d
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] WARNING: You are running linux kernel version 3.2.0-4-amd64, which might be unstable running docker. Please upgrade your kernell to 3.8.0.
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix(/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)
INFO[0000] WARNING: mountpoint for memory not found
INFO[0000] Loading containers: stat.
INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.
FATA[0000] inotify_add_watch: no such file or directory
```

The debug mode doesn't say more. Any suggestion would be appreciated, I couldn't find anybody having the inotify_add_watch message while trying to launch the docker daemon. Could it be because I'm running kernel 3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that's the Docker's 1.5.0 causing the issue. Solved by installing version 1.4.1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your docker service is not running.

You can start it with:

```
 service docker start
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention, when I start the docker service, I get no error (showing the green [ok] as usual), but still the daemon is not launched.

Comment: try running docker version with sudo

Comment: sudo is not configured on my system, i'm launching the daemon as root. I don't have the error anymore with the *lxc-docker-1.4.1*. Thanks for your help anyway :)